# Automating Word Document Processing with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, office-interop

I am trying to create a process, in my Asp.net application, that will open up a Microsoft Word template (stored on the server) and edit specific fields in the document then download the file to the users desktop.  This works fine on my local server but when pushed to our production server, it fails (no errors or warnings). Here is the code I have:

```
location = mappedPath & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("defaultTemplate")
Dim objWordApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
objWordApp.Visible = False
Dim objDoc As Word.Document = objWordApp.Documents.Open(location)
objDoc.Activate() 
objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="[SomeField]", ReplaceWith:=myField,    Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="[someId]", ReplaceWith:=myId,    Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
outputLocation = mappedPath & "Temp/Posting_" & Now.ToString("MMddyyyy_hhmmss") & ".docx"
objDoc.SaveAs(outputLocation)

objDoc.Close(Word.wdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)
objDoc = Nothing
objWordApp.Quit(Word.wdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)
objWordApp = Nothing
```

The code then goes on to send the outputlocation to the response.Write buffer, like this:

```
  Dim fi As FileInfo = New FileInfo(outputLocation)
  If fi.Exists Then
     Response.Clear()
     Response.ClearHeaders()
     Response.ClearContent()
     Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
     Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
     Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Server.UrlEncode(fi.Name))
     Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword")
     Response.ContentType = "application/msword"
     Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length.ToString())
     Response.WriteFile(fi.FullName)
     HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
 Else
    'log it
 End If
```

This code fails, on the server, at this line:

```
Dim objDoc As Word.Document = objWordApp.Documents.Open(location)
```

From what I have read, Microsoft does not support the automation of Office products on a server side.  That being said, is there a way to fix this or is there an alternative?  I have verified that the server that is running the app has Word installed and the user has the correct permissions.

As I stated, I need to be able to read/edit a file on the server and download the file to the user.  If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You stated that the code fails, on the server, at this line:

Dim objDoc As Word.Document = objWordApp.Documents.Open(location)

Are you able to add a debugger to the application and see what the exact error is?

It could be several things:

1. Location might be incorrect
2. word.dll might not be accessible
3. Version of word might be different

Regards,

Comment: This application is located on the server, and I am unable to debug.  But, i do log any errors.  No error is produced, it just hangs.

Comment: @jason Were you able to find a solution for this?